# keeping trailing zeros in prettyNum()

Tags: r

I need to print my numbers with the same number of trailing zeros (automatically "guessed" for each input), and can't find the right parameter in `prettyNum()`. What I want is the following:

```
prettyNum(c(1, 1.1, 2), ...)
# "1.0" "1.1" "2.0"

prettyNum(c(100, 1.1, 2, 2.25), ...)
# "100.00" "  1.10" "  2.00" "  2.25"
```

Comment: `format(x, trim = TRUE)` Is this what you want?

Comment: @DarrenTsai almost! it does not add leading padding spaces (for example, if `x=c(1,1234.1)`). My bad, I should have clarified this requirement in my question.

Comment: I see your edit! If you need the leading padding spaces, why `format(x)` not work?

Comment: omg you're right!!! honestly I didn't even try checking `format()` because I started from `prettyNum()` ‍♂️

Comment: too bad the other user deleted their answer with the whole thread of comments, it was actually quite useful too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format()` can easily achieve what you want.

```r
format(c(1, 1.1, 2))
# [1] "1.0" "1.1" "2.0"

format(c(100, 1.1, 2, 2.25))
# [1] "100.00" "  1.10" "  2.00" "  2.25"
```

If you don't need the leading spaces, just add `trim = TRUE`.

Comment: Neat, never noticed this even works for different toys `format(c('*', '', '***'))`, upvoted!